# Flex: apply max-height to a child element while preventing it from taking the space it doesn't need

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `flex` container with 2 child elements, sharing the same space (`flex-grow: 1`). Each of them has `overflow: auto` set. They look like this:

[image]

The idea is the following:

- if the 2 children have enough content, keep both child elements at the max-height of 50% of the parent
- if the **first** child has less content, though, shrink it to its
  content; basically make sure it doesn't use the 50% of the parent if it doesn't need to
- the **second** child always occupies the rest of the parent's space

So, in the case shown above, I really want this:

[image]

I am aware of the `flex-shrink` property in CSS, I've tried to use it but I must be doing it wrong. Any help?

**The code:** ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpq2f6qz/))

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="child one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</div>
  <div class="child two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  max-height: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.one {
  background-color: #6799d2;
  max-height: 19%;
}

.two {
  background-color: #67d375;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the maximum height of the children, don't allow them to grow but allow them to shrink when possible.

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.one {
  background-color: #6799d2;
  max-height: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.two {
  background-color: #67d375;
  flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="child one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</div>
  <div class="child two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.child` elements not occupying full height of parent `#container`.

Comment: @Gerard Unfortunately, the second child doesn't occupy the rest of the parent. See the fiddle (parent container has black background): https://jsfiddle.net/9t2uzmne/

Comment: @lesssugar Than the description doesn't match the image of what the end result should be.

Comment: @Gerard True, but the parent container, normally, would be transparent anyway, right? Also, take a look at the last bullet point in my post. Wasn't my intention to confuse anybody.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the second one a max-height of 100%:

```
.two {
  max-height: 100%
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?